# Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 2]

Tags: python, pip, installation

I`ve recently started having problems with pip installs. Every time I run this kind of command in Terminal, I get an error:

Could not install packages due to:

> EnvironmentError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/'me'/'me'/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tqdm-4.11.2.dist-info/METADATA'

Does anyone know what's wrong? Didn't have this issue a month ago. Please help!
Just in case: the error above popped up when i wrote pip install gender-guesser.

Comment: Reinstall `tqdm`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to reinstall tqdm with conda.
And then you can install packages with pip.

```
conda install tqdm
```

Wait until it done. Then you can do:

```
pip install gender-guesser
```

Comment: Please include example commands to show how this would be done.

Comment: `conda install tqdm`. Wait until it done. Then you try `pip install gender-guesser`

Answer (score 5):

I met the same problem and this might work for you
cd into the location where metadata.json exists and type this command  cp metadata.json METADATA then you could do sudo pip install

Answer (score 3):

I faced the same problem.

> Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/myusr/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip-19.0.1.dist-info/METADATA'

I followed the angrypig298 solution but it didn't work for me. The first part was ok.

```
conda install tqdm
```

But the second part got the same error of pip cannot find the METADATA file.

```
pip install gender-guesser
```

Based on other answers, I used the find command to find the METADATA in my machine and I found it in a subdirectory.

```
find ~/.local/ -name  "*METADATA*" | grep pip
```

The METADATA was in

```
/home/myuser/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip-19.0.1.dist-info/pip-19.0.1.dist-info/METADATA
```

I copy it to the path where the pip command is looking for it, which is one directory above it.

```
/home/myuser/.local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pip-9.0.1.dist-info/METADATA
```

Then the pip worked normally.

Answer (score 2):

I use Pycharm.
I have solved with problem with copy file METADATA from \AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\pip-19.0.1.dist-info\pip-19.0.1.dist-info
to higher level \AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\pip-19.0.1.dist-info

Comment: This also worked for me. It seems that pip-19.0.1 installed the METADATA file inside a subdirectory with the same name (this is all for the --user option within Windows). I just upgraded to 19.1.1 (python -m pip install --upgrade pip --user), and it seems to have fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

One solution is to remove the folder containing `METADATA`, and then try to re-install the package. By doing it, we're forcing Python to install a new one, instead of looking for an existing folder.

For example: `No such file or directory: /user/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/the_folder/METADATA`

With command line, it would be

```
$ rm -rf /user/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/the_folder
```

Then, install the package again. It should work.

Answer (score 0):

copy all the files in "/home/shuaizhang/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip-19.0.1.dist-info/pip-19.0.1.dist-info/" to the upper directory "/home/shuaizhang/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip-19.0.1.dist-info/"

Then, pip3 install --user --upgrade pip , solved my problem.

I hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

```
cd /'me'/'me'/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/
ls misbehaving-package*
```

In my case I had multiple versions of the same package with one only containing a `direct_url.json` - this was the misbehaving one. I simply `rm` it and ran the install again, which solved the problem.

Answer (score -4):

I find the `METADATA` file in this path or this path subdirctory, then cp this file

Comment: This is not a complete answer. Write it down so that future users that will have the same problem can resolve it by reading your answer