# getting environment error while installing python packages

Tags: python, pip

I have been facing environment error while installing python package.

> Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/gamut/.conda/envs/tf_3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pexpect-4.6.0.dist-info/METADATA'

I have gone through this directory and found this files:

> DESCRIPTION.rst
>   metadata.json

I am getting same error when installing packages inside or outside the environment.
Any method to solve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: \[Errno 2\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51617284/could-not-install-packages-due-to-an-environmenterror-errno-2)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+EnvironmentError%3A+Errno+2+No+such+file+or+directory

Comment: In your case you need to reinstall `pexpect` in environment `tf_3`.

Comment: I get this error when install pexpect:
 
TypeError: string argument expected, got 'NoneType'