# Try to install python packages with the help of pip

Tags: python, pip

in python try installing packages using pip but it showing this
Couldn't install packages due to Environment Error [Errno:2] 
[image showing what error I am getting][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xrFbU.png)

Comment: update pip to the newest version and try

Comment: I also try to update the pip but it is also showing the error

Comment: C:\Users\Adhikansh>python -m pip install --upgrade pip
Collecting pip
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/d8/f3/413bab4ff08e1fc4828
dfc59996d721917df8e8583ea85385d51125dceff/pip-19.0.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 2] No such file or
 directory: 'c:\\users\\adhikansh\\appdata\\roaming\\python\\python37\\site-pack
ages\\pip-19.0.1.dist-info\\METADATA'
You are using pip version 19.0.1, however version 19.0.3 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' comm and.`

Comment: `python -m pip install --upgrade pip` is this by default upgrading the version 3?

Comment: did you uninstall python and installed it once again in past? I'll suggest you to look up this link maybe it helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51617284/could-not-install-packages-due-to-an-environmenterror-errno-2

Comment: yes i installed it again.

Comment: It is not yet working...

C:\Users\Adhikansh\Desktop>pip install gender-guesser
Collecting gender-guesser
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/13/fb/3f2aac40cd2421e164ca
b1668e0ca10685fcf896bd6b3671088f8aab356e/gender_guesser-0.4.0-py2.py3-none-any.w
hl (379kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 389kB 303kB/s
Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 2] No such file or
 directory: 'c:\\users\\adhikansh\\appdata\\roaming\\python\\python37\\site-pack
ages\\pip-19.0.1.dist-info\\METADATA'

Comment: did you go through that link?

Comment: yes i go after that this problem come again

Answer (score 0):

Try running your command with superuser rights.

`sudo -H pip3 install ...`

On Windows you could try to start the cmd with admin rights as described here: https://www.howtogeek.com/194041/how-to-open-the-command-prompt-as-administrator-in-windows-8.1/