# Got the ImportError: cannot import name 'PandasError'

Tags: python, pandas

My pandas was workable, but after half year, it could not be imported again.
I have googled the previous solutions but could not solve my problem.
When got:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'PandasError'
```

try:

```
conda install pandas

conda update -n base conda
```

And get the same error again:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'PandasError'
```

try:

```
pip install -U pandas-datareader
```

get:

```
WARNING: No metadata found in /anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas-0.24.2.dist-info/METADATA'
```

Please help to let it run again.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/sS465rmv contains the original content of that pandas metadata file, so if all else fails you could always create a new `/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas-0.24.2.dist-info/METADATA` file and paste the content in.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to run:

```
conda install pandas
```

And didn't work?

So do like said in [here:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51617284/could-not-install-packages-due-to-an-environmenterror-errno-2)

First, try to reinstall tqdm with conda. And then you can install packages with pip.

```
conda install tqdm
```

Wait until it done. Then you can do:

```
pip install gender-guesser
```

Later

```
conda install pandas
```