# ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:

Tags: python, windows

```
C:\Users\Karan Shah>pip3 install geograpy3
Collecting geograpy3
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/57/3e/881a580f03ee257b61b157bc82b011d35cb3174da1b5f48dbeae38c64b87/geograpy3-0.1.2-py3-none-any.whl (1.3MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 1.3MB 52kB/s
Collecting jellyfish (from geograpy3)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/3f/80/bcacc7affb47be7279d7d35225e1a932416ed051b315a7f9df20acf04cbe/jellyfish-0.7.2.tar.gz (133kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 143kB 36kB/s
Collecting newspaper3k (from geograpy3)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/d7/b9/51afecb35bb61b188a4b44868001de348a0e8134b4dfa00ffc191567c4b9/newspaper3k-0.2.8-py3-none-any.whl (211kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 215kB 99kB/s
Collecting pycountry (from geograpy3)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/16/b6/154fe93072051d8ce7bf197690957b6d0ac9a21d51c9a1d05bd7c6fdb16f/pycountry-19.8.18.tar.gz (10.0MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 10.0MB 19kB/s
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\KARANS~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-req-tracker-1p49m0w2\\4cd6b7124980423f794a16dde7409d3854593dcba017033b202bba61'
```

Comment: This is not related to visual-studio-code, so that tag should not be used.  Did you try doing a web search for this error message?  If so, how does your situation compare to what you found?

Comment: Maybe this is helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51617284/could-not-install-packages-due-to-an-environmenterror-errno-2 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54778630/could-not-install-packages-due-to-an-environmenterror-errno-2-no-such-file-or/55479841

Answer (score 0):

Try Setting up python variable as environment variable

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow @Raghav gupta! Please elaborate on your answer and - if possible - show how to implement your suggestion, so the asker can act on your suggested answer.