# Trying to Install jedi: Errno 2

Tags: python-3.x, pip, python-jedi

I am trying to install jedi using Windows Command Prompt. I type `pip install jedi`

But I end up with this error:

```
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError:
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\Adrian Lewis\\AppData\\Local\\Packages\\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\\LocalCache\\local-packages\\Python37\\site-packages\\jedi\\third_party\\typeshed\\third_party\\2and3\\requests\\packages\\urllib3\\packages\\ssl_match_hostname\\_implementation.pyi'
```

What can I do to fix this? **I am trying to ultimately install jupyter**, but this seems to be preventing me from doing that. Let me know if more information is needed, I am new to Python and programming in general.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: \[Errno 2\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51617284/could-not-install-packages-due-to-an-environmenterror-errno-2)