# OpenAI Whisper Cannot Import Numpy

Tags: python, numpy, openai-whisper

I am trying to run the OpenAI Whisper model but running into the following error when trying to run my script:

> ValueError: Unable to compare versions for numpy>=1.17: need=1.17 found=None. This is unusual. Consider reinstalling numpy.

I have, as the error suggests, tried reinstalling Numpy but that didn't solve anything. When I run the command 'pip show numpy' I get:

```
Name: numpy
Version: 1.23.5
Summary: NumPy is the fundamental package for array computing with Python.
Home-page: https://www.numpy.org
Author: Travis E. Oliphant et al.
Author-email: 
License: BSD
Location: /opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages
Requires: 
Required-by: contourpy, matplotlib, pandas, pythran, scipy, transformers, whisper
```

So not only do I have Numpy version 1.23.5 (>1.17), it also lists whisper as dependent on the package.

My machine is a Macbook Air M1 running OS Ventura 13.0.1.

I have looked through the OpenAI github for similar issues but I can't seem to find anything of the sort. I also tried importing the package manually with this following:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/numpy')
```

But this didn't work either. Please let me know if you have any insight as to why this may be happening.

Comment: Are you sure the `pip` points to the same python as the one that throws the "no numpy" error?

Comment: How would I go about verifying that? I did install both numpy and the whisper packages with pip and pip3, and am running them with python3. I'm guessing if anything that whisper would be trying to look elsewhere.

Comment: How do you run the code that uses the whisper package? Do you do `python ...`? If so, do `python -m pip install numpy` to install numpy to that python. This gets rid of the problem of multiple `pip` commands pointing to different pythons

Comment: I do python3.... I did try 'python3 -m pip install numpy' but that didn't fix anything unfortunately

Comment: I tried uninstalling with the same command and then reinstalling, now I'm getting this error: 'ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/numpy-1.23.5.dist-info/METADATA'' To clarify I get this error when trying to reinstall using the aformentioned command

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51617284/could-not-install-packages-due-to-an-environmenterror-errno-2 IDK why Whisper doesn't find numpy, hopefully someone else can help. Good luck!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to resolve this issue by navigating to the directory printed by 'pip show numpy', which in my case was "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages"

From there, there were some loose numpy related folders despite uninstalling numpy. I deleted these folders and reinstalled numpy using

```
python3 -m pip install numpy
```

After doing this my code worked as expected.

Comment: This fixed your original problem (Whisper can't find numpy) too? Interesting! I suspect you just needed to reinstall numpy, and the folders needed to be deleted to fix the METADATA folder issue